# oracle translate function is giving error to convert in number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to remove the first and last quote from a string to use it in clause. When I run the following query ::

```
with t as (
     select '1,2,3' x from dual)
select translate(x, ' '||chr(39)||chr(34), ' ' ) from t
```

it gives the result > 1,2,3

But when I run the following query ::

```
    select * from care_topic_templates where care_topic_id in (
with t as (
         select '1,2,3' x from dual)
    select translate(x, ' '||chr(39)||chr(34), ' ' ) from t
);
```

it gives this error > `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are comparing an integer `id` to a string, which looks like `'1,2,3'` -- and this string cannot be converted to an integer, even after the strange substitutions using `translate()`. Strings are not lists.

You can do what you want using `like` and a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from care_topic_templates
where exists (select 1
              from (select '1,2,3' as x from dual) x
              where ',' || x || ',' like '%,' || care_topic_id || ',%'
             );
```

Or, in your case:

```
select *
from care_topic_templates
where exists (select 1
              from (select '1,2,3' as x from dual) x
              where ',' || translate(x, ' '||chr(39)||chr(34), ' ') || ',' like '%,' || care_topic_id || ',%'
             );
```

This is following the logic of your query.  There are other ways to express this logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is great help.

Comment: Can you suggest what to do for same result but for double quote instead of single

Comment: @SumonBappi . . . You should ask another question.

Comment: I have done it in my application service. Thank you for your reply.